# (SSR) How to get Fragment Types for IntrospectionFragmentMatcher on the server?

Tags: apollo-client, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to get the fragmentTypes directly from a schema?

The docs for [IntrospectionFragmentMatcher](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/fragments.html#fragment-matcher) show how to fetch and store these in a JSON file - but it seems to only consider client-side use and assumes that you have a running server.

Since I'm using the same server as my GraphQL API as well as for rendering the app, it's a chicken-and-egg thing. I could still do this as the docs say with an extra build step, but that would essentially mean:

1. Build from src
2. Start up server
3. Run script to extract fragment types, write these to a `.json` file
4. Restart the server

I feel like there must be a simpler way to do this.

When rendering the app, I'm creating a new Apollo client with a `SchemaLink`, so I already have a fully prepared schema.

Right now I have this:

```js
import introspectionQueryResultData from './fragmentTypes.json'

const fragmentMatcher = new IntrospectionFragmentMatcher({
    introspectionQueryResultData,
})


const render = ({ schema, context }) => async (req, res, next) => {
    const client = new ApolloClient({
        ssrMode: true,
        link: new SchemaLink({ schema, context }),
        cache: new InMemoryCache({
            fragmentMatcher,
        }),
    })
    // ...
```

I'd like to be able to something like this instead:

```js
const render = ({ schema, context }) => async (req, res, next) => {
    const client = new ApolloClient({
        ssrMode: true,
        link: new SchemaLink({ schema, context }),
        cache: new InMemoryCache({
            fragmentMatcher: fragmentMatcherFromSchema(schema)
        }),
    })
    // ...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely possible, but I haven't tried doing it fully in runtime yet.
However, you can avoid having to have to run start the server to extract the fragments.

If you are using GraphQL-Code-Generator (https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/).

You can specify various input for the schema other than a url where the server is running see:
https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/schema-field#available-formats

You can at least reduce the steps to

1. Build from src
2. Run script to extract fragment types, write these to a .json file
3. Start up server